# Interactive Graph for Android application

Tags: java, android, user-interface, frontend

How to create a graph similar to the MiBand UI, I'm new to Android UI development. I would like to slide/scroll the graph horizontally and the values bound to it in the x-axis must also move along. Another thing I'm looking forward is to highlight the bar when it is pointed by the value pointer on the x-axis.

[image]